# What word should I use to express the feeling of stepping on a banana's peel or walking on an oily floor?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am curious about the word I should use to express my feeling when I step on a banana's peel, touch on an oily surface, or walk on an oily floor. My feeling is smooth and moving fast. I don't know what word should I use to express this feeling.

Comment: [meet onelook](http://onelook.com/?w=smooth+and+moving+fast&ls=a)

Comment: @MattЭллен Which word (on your link) is the answer?

Comment: You may use any word you like.

Comment: I agree with KitFox, but I think _slip_ is [most common](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=slipped+on+a+banana+peel%2C+fell+on+a+banana+peel%2C+glided+on+a+banana+peel%2C+slid+on+a+banana+peel%2C+tripped+on+a+banana+peel&year_start=1880&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=).

Comment: A more generic term for the kind of "feeling" would be *glide*. (***glide***  
/glīd/
Verb
**Move with a smooth, quiet continuous motion**: "gondolas glided past".
Noun
**A smooth continuous movement**.
Synonyms
verb.   *slide* - *slip* - *slither*
noun.   *slide* - *gliding* - *slip* - *glissade*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use [slip](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/slip), and its derivation [slippery](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/slippery) or more informally [slippy](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/slippy).

> When I stepped on the banana peel, I slipped.
>
> The oily floor was very slippery.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the word *[slid](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/slide?q=slid)*.

> As I stepped on the banana peel I slid, and nearly lost my footing.
>
> As I stepped on the oily floor I slid some distance before regaining my footing.

Or you could use the word *[skidded](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/skid?q=skid)*.

> My foot skidded as I stepped on the banana skin and I lost my footing.
>
> I skidded on the oily floor as I stepped onto it.